# Adobe AIR for iOS 26+ StageWebView does not load local HTML from documentsDirectory

Tags: ios, air, adobe

I have been using AIR for iOS to build iOS apps that download HTML files locally and load them through stageWebView for years, until AIR 26 came out. It stopped loading local html from documentsDirectory. I received the error message below -

> stagewebview.loadURL(path) returns an error - not able to reach
>   location:[ErrorEvent type="error" bubbles=false cancelable=false
>   eventPhase=2 text="The operation couldn't be completed.
>   (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 1.)" errorID=3228]

I've tried using both ways to get the file path and both returned the above error. It just cannot find the location of the files saved locally -

1.

```
var destination:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("29/index.html");
var fp = destination.nativePath;
path = "file://" + fp;
webView.loadURL(path);
```

2.

```
var destination:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("29/index.html");
path = new File(destination.nativePath).url;
webView.loadURL(path);
```

I even tried with changing url file scheme to "**file://**", "**file:///**", and "**file:////**" and none of them find the files saved in **documentsDirectory** from AIR26 and AIR 27 beta. The code worked for AIR 25 and below.

I tried loading the html from applicationStorageDirectory and it just cannot find the html files either.

Here is the file path in the documentsDirectory - 
*file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/device-specific-code/Documents/29/index.html*

I am confused why the same exact code worked for AIR 25 and below but stopped working since AIR 26.

I have searched all over the place and can't find any real answers.

Any insights/solutions/workaround are all appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having the problem that I cannot load local PDF files anymore into the StageWebView. I am on iOS 11.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, only a workaround: use Air version 25. [Since version 26 Adobe uses WKWebView instead of UIWebView](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_26_air_26_release_notes.html) and at least with their implementation this means local files can not be loaded. Luckily, apps compiled with AIR 25 run on iOS 11.